# given a perfect hash function, compute inclusion

Tags: hash

Given a perfect hash function over a set of integers S, can one compute the inclusion of an integer in S, i.e. if an integer is not in S, can you tell without reading from the hash table itself, and if an integer is in S, can you tell without reading the hash table? Assume we have a minimal perfect hash function. So the size of the hash table is n and the size of S is m, and n=m. I apologize if this is obvious.

Comment: If the hash function is "over a set of integers S", how would you go about determining that `i` is not in `S`? Would you expect the hash routine to throw an exception for "not in S"? Return a special flag value?

Comment: I suppose any boolean return value would work, I just don't want to read the hash table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, because a perfect hash function maps every possible integer to an index.

What you can do is: for each key, store only *some* additional information, for example the last few bits of the hash code of that key. That way, you can say (with a configurable probability; it depends on how much data you store) whether or not the integer is *likely* in the set or not. This is basically the same as a bloom filter (you can get false positives, but not false negatives).

Comment: I hadn't considered something like bloom filter, on my particular GPU application the bloom filter will fit in shared memory so this is very good. Thank you for taking the time to answer, apologies for the delay, never got a notification.